# Declaring with commas in C++

Tags: c++

I know

```
int* p, k;
```

declares `k` to be `int` and `p` to be `int*`, but how about:

```
static int a, b;
const int c, d;
```

and other declarators. Is it the same for all of them? Obviously for pointers, arrays, and indirection it would be.

I'm not asking if it compiles; I'm asking for rules regarding these declarations, preferably quoted from the standard.

Comment: Have you tried to compile it?

Comment: @n.m. compile what?

Comment: But yeah, try assigning to `d` and compiling :)

Comment: Regardless of "correctness" and behavior. General rule of thumb, declare each variable on its own line and intialize it (if needed).  And give them meaningful names. Writing good C++ is not about putting as much on one line as you can.

Comment: If you want chapter-and-verse from the standard, consider using the `language-lawyer` tag.

Comment: `int* p` is misleading. * here us a separate lexem, not a part of type declarator. `int *p` or `int * p` is more correct and hints at what actually happens here.

Comment: Where can I find more information on this @Swift-FridayPie

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't take much to test this. The following does not compile because `p` has been declared `const`.   https://godbolt.org/z/P7bj85aWx

```
int main() {
    const int k = 1, p = 5;

    p++;
   
    return 0; 
}
```

For `static`, consider the following which outputs `67` rather than `66`. The latter would be expected if `b` were *not* `static`.

https://godbolt.org/z/E58azYdfe.

```
#include <iostream>

int foo() {
    static int a, b = 5;

    b++;

    return b;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << foo() << foo() << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```